# Connecting A Three-Phase Motor for a Circular Saw

Tags: motor, three-phase

i have a table saw where i want to switch out the motor for a 3-phase one.
I already have the motor and also a motor protection circuit, but i am not sure about how to connect it.

This is the switch with protection:

[image: protection circuit]

For this Motor (also still unsure about whether i want star or delta connection, but i guess i need to compare the motor speed with the old one):
[image: Motor]

And for completeness, this is the tablesaw in question:
[image: The Saw]

If i understand it correctly, the left part is undervoltage protection. But i am not sure about how to wire it, and what the additional switch on the right is used for. I Already tried looking at the datasheets but to no avail. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.
Also, is it possible to add a seperate "mushroom head" switch for emergency shutoff?
I suspect i would need another 3-phase relay for it sadly.
Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: For emergency stop you need a 3-phase contactor, DPDT relay, emergency stop button, monentary and momentary power on pushbutton. One leg of the DPDT relay is wired to latch on with the pushbutton while the other leg controls the contactor. The emergency stop breaks the latching power for the DPDT relay. That way if you hit the emergency stop and immediately reset it, the power stays off. THe pushbutton must be pressed to re-engage power. If you're lucky your saw has most of that in place already except for the three-phase contactor.

Comment: Ok, then, ignoring the point about the Emergency, i am still confused about how to wire it with just the switch i have. I mean, obviously the middle block cuts the three phases, but how do i connect the undervoltage protection, and what is the point of the other one? It seems to be some kind of auxiliary switch...

Comment: I am not familiar with how the undervoltage works so can't offer guidance. Presumably the undervoltage somehow taps into the 3-phase input lines to detect the voltage and has an output switch which opens or closes based on that. If so, that output switch would be connected to energize or de-energize the control input on the three-phase contactor which controls whether the motor is connected to the 3-phase input power or not. To be honest, I am not sure why a saw would need undervoltage protection. Overcurrent would make more sense.

Comment: It seems the undervoltage switch is not for "undervoltage" but is more intended for a "loss of power" safety mechanism for the same purpose as the emergency stop mechanism I described earlier. It is so that if the power goes out, the equipment doesn't just suddenly turn on when power comes back. Knowing those two things should help guide you but there is a Woodworking SE which is probably more familiar with this.

Comment: How it comes together depends on how much of this task the UV switch handles. Because it could range from adding the UV switch to the E-stop circuit if it all it does is open a contact when voltage is too low, all the way to doing everything (such as latching power on) inside it, in which case all that is required is to add an E-stop switch to be able to manually unlatch the UV switch. How to use it is probably called the "manual" and not the "datasheet" in this case if you can find it.

Comment: The middle block actually has "loss of power" protection already, as it mechanically connects to the switch, and it only stays in the "on" position if there is Voltage on it. The "undervoltage" part is this one: 
https://datasheet.eaton.com/datasheet.php?model=073135&locale=en_GB
I think somehow attaches to the middle switch... but it has only 2 terminals - so i am unsure how i should wire it.

Comment: Are those just mounted next to each other or do they have connections going into each other as they are mounted adjacently? Because this here indicates the auxillary contact and circuit breaker tap into each other: https://datasheet.eaton.com/datasheet.php?model=072896&locale=ro If the UV voltage module also taps into the circuit breaker then that would make sense but it's not clear to me from the photos or datasheet. But if it does then that means that the UV module already has control of the circuit breaker.

Comment: I think they are only mechanically connected...

Comment: Disassemble them and look. It might not be an electrical interface but a mechanical one. There appears to be extra pieces sticking into the breaker that don't seem strictly necessary if they were just mounted adjacently. https://www.eaton.com/ro/en-gb/skuPage.073129.resources.html